# How to get only html table row columns with values?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know if there is an easier way of getting only the html table row columns with values,

here is a sample table image

[image]

and here is what I wanted it to become

[image]

```html
 <table id="tblPayslipApproval" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tbody>
    <tr class="tr-border-full">
      <td style="min-width:50px">EARNINGS</td>
      <td style="min-width:50px"></td>
      <td style="min-width:50px" class="td-border-right"></td>
      <td style="min-width:50px" align="center" colspan="3" class="td-border-right">DEDUCTIONS</td>
      <td style="min-width:50px" align="center" colspan="3" class="td-border-right">LOAN BALANCES</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-border-full">
      <td style="min-width:50px">DESCRIPTION</td>
      <td style="min-width:50px"></td>
      <td style="min-width:50px" class="number-align td-border-right">AMOUNT</td>
      <td style="min-width:50px">DESCRIPTION</td>
      <td style="min-width:50px"></td>
      <td style="min-width:50px" class="number-align td-border-right">AMOUNT</td>
      <td style="min-width:50px">DESCRIPTION</td>
      <td style="min-width:50px"></td>
      <td style="min-width:50px" class="number-align td-border-right">AMOUNT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="min-width:50px" class="td-border-left">&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="min-width:50px">&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="min-width:50px" class="td-border-right">&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="min-width:50px">&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="min-width:50px">&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="min-width:50px" class="td-border-right">&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="min-width:50px">&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="min-width:50px">&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="min-width:50px" class="td-border-right">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="min-width:50px" class="td-border-left">Basic Pay</td>
      <td style="min-width:50px"></td>
      <td style="min-width:50px" class="number-align td-border-right"><span id="preview_basic_pay"> 18,655.88 </span></td>
      <td style="min-width:50px">SSS EE Contribution</td>
      <td style="min-width:50px"></td>
      <td style="min-width:50px" class="number-align td-border-right"><span id="preview_sss_ee_contrib1"> 581.30 </span></td>
      <td style="min-width:50px"></td>
      <td style="min-width:50px"></td>
      <td style="min-width:50px" class="number-align td-border-right"><span id="preview_sss_ee_contrib2"></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="min-width:50px" class="td-border-left"></td>
      <td style="min-width:50px"></td>
      <td style="min-width:50px" class="number-align td-border-right"></td>
      <td style="min-width:50px">PhilHealth EE Contribution</td>
      <td style="min-width:50px"></td>
      <td style="min-width:50px" class="number-align td-border-right"><span id="preview_philhealth_ee_contrib1"> 256.52 </span></td>
      <td style="min-width:50px"></td>
      <td style="min-width:50px"></td>
      <td style="min-width:50px" class="number-align td-border-right"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="min-width:50px" class="td-border-left"> </td>
      <td style="min-width:50px"></td>
      <td style="min-width:50px" class="number-align td-border-right"></td>
      <td style="min-width:50px">PAGIBIG EE Contribution</td>
      <td style="min-width:50px"></td>
      <td style="min-width:50px" class="number-align td-border-right"><span id="preview_pagibig_ee_contrib1"> 100.00 </span></td>
      <td style="min-width:50px"></td>
      <td style="min-width:50px"></td>
      <td style="min-width:50px" class="number-align td-border-right"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Here is my draft code, I'm not sure if I'm in the right path or if there's a simpler way of doing it,

```
$.each("table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3)", function(){
    var $elem = $(this);
    if($elem.text() == " - "){
       $elem.prev().text("");
       $elem.text("");
    }
})

$.each("table > tbody > tr:nth-child(6)", function(){
    var $elem = $(this);
    if($elem.text() == " - "){
       $elem.prev().text("");
       $elem.text("");
    }
})

$.each("table > tbody > tr:nth-child(9)", function(){
    var $elem = $(this);
    if($elem.text() == " - "){
       $elem.prev().text("");
       $elem.text("");
    }
})
```

After removing the values of "-" columns, I have to arrange the rows, and fill-in the gaps,

Is there any other way to make it simpler,

Thank You,!

Comment: why are you using 3,6, 9th child ?

Comment: That table leaves a lot to be desired. Headings should be in a head block, and there shouldn't be random headings scattered through the data. If it was organized better you'd have a much easier time of it.

Comment: There are lot of missing things in your question , like "-" things, what do you mean by fill in the gaps ? What is your expected output ?

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra im using the 3rd, 6th and 9th child to check values the amount columns, because 3rd, 6th, and 9th columns are my amount columns,

Comment: @isherwood I know the table format is not good, however it is the standard format I have to follow because its the original format of the payslip given to me,

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra the " - " is the columns with no set amount, like basic pay adjustment, overtime pay,  sss ee contrib, philhealth ee and pag ibig ee contrib, What I meant of fill in the gaps is to remove those empty columns if there are no amount values in it and retain only those columns with amount values,

Comment: I have added my expected output, Thank you all,

Comment: Why don't you add Table having "-" so that someone can first see the problem and then your solution ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#tblPayslipApproval tr").find("td:contains('-')").each(function(k,v){
        $(v).prev().prev().html("");
        $(v).html("");
    });


});
```